Feeding boosted voltage to same IC power pin
Can we feed boosted voltage to power pin of logic IC 74HC14? When battery voltage drops to 2 V after usage, still I should get more than 2.5 V at gate outputs.
IC runs on two 1.5 V battery in series. One of its gate (pins 12 and 13) is used as DC-DC boost 4.5 to 5 V. Power pin 14 connected to battery and also to boosted voltage.
Can we use this boosted voltage to feed power pin of the same IC package?


What does the datasheet say?

What Spehro says. Vdd max operating is 6V. You MUST keep it to <= 6V. || I have used this circuit with great success with regulated feedback. What is your Vout and load? I MAY be able to offer a very useful circuit.

@RussellMcMahon - Hi, In case it helps you to avoid duplication of effort here, you have already given this answer to a previous version of the question from the OP.

As per the IC datasheet I found on the internet, the supply allowed is 2-6V. So, if your boosted voltage is lower than that, the IC should be able to handle it. I assume that the square wave levels that you feed to pin 13 are also 0-VCC. So, I don't see a concern.

Bootstrapping should work, however this will operate in discontinuous mode so you'll get enough voltage to fry the  74HC14.

How to control the voltage,  should be under 4.5V , shouldn't use series regulator and high cost dc dc step down , any low quiescent current regulator  around 200uA available?

Yes, there are low Iq regulators, but in this case I would suggest adding feedback so you don't waste so much power.

Pls link me the feedback circuit

@Hars I don't have a suitable image to link. Probably something like a Zener and additional transistor to inhibit the oscillator or drive circuit. You might want to ping Russell M. who has offered (above) and who usually has excellent suggestions.
